# When ShowInTaskBar is set to false, minimizing creates a visible bar on desktop

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms

How to get rid of this visible bar when the window is minimized?

[image: Visible bar]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        }

        private void notifyIcon1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
            {
                this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            }

            else if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal)
            {
                this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
            }
        }

        private void menuItem1_Click(object Sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Close the form, which closes the application.
            this.Close();
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Rectangle workingArea = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea;
            int left = workingArea.Width - this.Width;
            int top = workingArea.Height - this.Height;

            this.Location = new Point(left, top);
        }
    }
}

namespace MyApp
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon notifyIcon1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu contextMenu1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem menuItem1;
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Form1));
            this.contextMenu1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu();
            this.menuItem1 = new System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem();
            this.notifyIcon1 = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon(this.components);
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // contextMenu1
            // 
            this.contextMenu1.MenuItems.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem[] {
            this.menuItem1});
            // 
            // menuItem1
            // 
            this.menuItem1.Index = 0;
            this.menuItem1.Text = "E&xit";
            this.menuItem1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.menuItem1_Click);
            // 
            // notifyIcon1
            // 
            this.notifyIcon1.ContextMenu = this.contextMenu1;
            this.notifyIcon1.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("notifyIcon1.Icon")));
            this.notifyIcon1.Text = "notifyIcon1";
            this.notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
            this.notifyIcon1.MouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.notifyIcon1_MouseClick);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            //this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(320, 240);
            this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            this.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon")));
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.ShowIcon = false;
            this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.Manual;
            this.TopMost = true;
            this.FormClosing += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler(this.Form1_FormClosing);
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyApp
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: set shownintaskbar to true only when it is minimized. users will want to have a way of un-minimizing. or use a tray icon and don't offer minimizability.

Comment: I think you need to show/hide the Form here and not minimize/restore it. Toggle the `Visible` property of the Form in the `notifyIcon1_MouseClick`. Also you can call `CenterToScreen();` in the constructor to center the Form.

Comment: @CeeMcSharpface: minimizing/maximizing is handled by the notifyicon clicks

Comment: I see. in this case set visible to false on minimize. you need to provide users a means to restore - when that is provided by the notification icon, fine.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up replacing `WindowState` with `hide()`, this hides the bar as well.

```
    private void notifyIcon1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Visible == true)
        {
            this.Hide();
        }
        else
        {
            this.Show();
        }
    }
```